# Integral of $\operatorname{cosech}^4 x$

Tags: integration, hyperbolic-functions

$\newcommand{\cosech}{\operatorname{cosech}}$

I ran into this integral when trying to solve a problem, and I could not get my head around it.

$$\int \cosech^4(x)dx$$

I tried to split into two $\text{cosech}^2(x)$ terms, and then substitute in the identity $\cosech^2(x)=\coth^2(x)-1$ to get:

$$
\begin{align}
& =\int \cosech^2(x)(\coth^2(x)-1)dx \\[8pt]
& =\int \left(\cosech^2(x)\coth^2(x) - \cosech^2(x) \right) \, dx \\[8pt]
& =\int \cosech^2(x)\coth^2(x)dx - \int\cosech^2(x) \, dx
\end{align}
$$

From here I was okay to integrate the second part, since its a standard integral, but I was really not sure what to do with the first part. I tried to use integrating by parts because that is what we've been doing in class, but it didn't get me anywhere.

So if anyone could give me some advice as to what do from here, or whether my whole method is kind of faulty, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you familiar with change of variable? If so, for this kind of integral you can try the change of variable $t=\exp x$.

Comment: (You could substitute $u=\coth(x)$ in the first integral.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No integration by parts necessary:

$$\int dx \, \text{csch}^4{x} = -\int d(\coth{x}) (\coth^2{x}-1) = -\frac13 \coth^3{x} - \coth{x}+C$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer seems to make sense to me, but I had one question. When I tried to calculate the integral on the Wolfram website, it gave me a different solution to yours. Their solution was: ∫cosech^4(x).dx = -(1/3)coth(x)[-2 + cosech^2(x)] + constant. In the step by step working they used a "reduction formula" which I've never seen before! So are the two results actually the same once simplified out? I was quite confused by this, and I tried to check whether the two results were equal by hand, but didn't manage to equate them correctly to each other. @Ron

Comment: @Mathsstruggler: use $\text{csch}^2{x}-\coth^2{x}=1$.